# Confusing syntax in a C typedef

Tags: c, typedef, c-preprocessor

Was hoping someone could help me decipher this C snippet:

```
typedef int (DEFCALL *getFieldVal)(int key, int fieldSelect, char *name)
```

DEFCALL is defined earlier in the code, but only as

```
#define DEFCALL
```

So, I think `DEFCALL` is just a blank, and I am effectively looking at

```
typedef int (*getFieldVal)(int key, int fieldSelect, char *name)
```

which defines getFieldVal as a pointer to a function that takes args int, int, and char*, and returns an integer.  But the `DEFCALL` has me wondering.  Wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `typedef` is defining a function pointer type. The `DEFCALL` is a preprocessor macro that may be defined to specify any platform specific calling convention information used by the function. In this case it is defined as nothing resulting in the compiler generating the default calling convention, usually `cdecl`.

Answer (score 6):

The macro leaves room for adding a calling convention to the function type.